# SELECT Múltiplo Range de data no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Pessoal tenho um problema para extrair datas em um range de treinamentos.
O que preciso é o seguinte se um treinamento teve seu início no dia 01/01/2017 e sua finalização no dia 03/03/2017 eleve deve retornar no select abaixo para os meses 01,02 e 03. Hoje esse select só me retorna os treinamentos que foram criados dentro de um Mês.

```
SELECT  distinct * 
FROM treinamentos,usuario_x_treinamento,usuario
WHERE status_treinamento = 'REALIZADO' 
AND treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento >='2017/01/1'
AND treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento <='2017/01/31'
AND usuario_x_treinamento.id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario
AND usuario_x_treinamento.id_treinamento = treinamentos.id_treinamentos;
```

Porém como estou usando o range somente na data de início não consigo fazer a seleção que eu preciso.

PS :  O select é executado para todos os meses do ano (é utilizado para gerar um relatório).

O que preciso é manter o range Mês a Mês mas também levar em consideração os treinamentos que se estenderem por mais de um mês.

Comment: A data do fim do treinamento está registrada no banco? Há uma quantidade de dias/meses fixo? há onde obter a duração do treinamento? Do contrário não tem como resolver essa questão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o DB estiver com formato de data, é bem simples (dá para fazer com string também, mas a performance é pior).

Supondo que você queira os treinamentos que estavam em vigor no mês `5` de `2017`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   *
FROM
   treinamentos,usuario_x_treinamento,usuario
WHERE
   status_treinamento = 'REALIZADO' 
   AND
      '201705' BETWEEN
      EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento) AND
      EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento)
   AND
      usuario_x_treinamento.id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario
   AND
      usuario_x_treinamento.id_treinamento = treinamentos.id_treinamentos;
```

Pontos de interesse:

- A função `EXTRACT` traz o ano e o mês de uma data no formato `YYYYMM` quando usada com `YEAR_MONTH`. No caso, use zeros à esquerda do mês para comparação;
- Como seu relatório é mensal, optamos por separar desta forma para ignorar o dia e evitar complicações de saber último dia do mês;
- A expressão `a BETWEEN c AND d`  equivale a `( a >= b AND a <= c )`, simplificando a leitura.

Comment: Acredito que seja exatamente isso que eu preciso, vou fazer o teste !

Comment: Bacco , fiz o teste é funcionou perfeitamente !!! Muito obrigado ! 
(Não consigo positivar pela minha reputação baixa mas marquei como resposta).